# Multiprocessing group apply python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, python-multiprocessing

I have two groups, one with the rows to be processed as groups, another with groups to be looked upon.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'Address1':['123 Cheese Way','234 Cookie Place','345 Pizza Drive','456 Pretzel Junction'],'city':['X','U','X','U']}) 
test2 = pd.DataFrame({'Address1':['123 chese wy','234 kookie Pl','345 Pizzza DR','456 Pretzel Junktion'],'city':['X','U','Z','Y'] , 'ID' : ['1','3','4','8']})

gr1 = test.groupby('city')
gr2 = test2.groupby('city')
```

Currently I am applying my function to every row of the group,

```
gr1.apply(lambda x: custom_func(x.Address1, gr2.get_group(x.name)))
```

However I don't know how to do multiprocessing on this. Please advise.

EDIT : - I tried to use `dask` , but I can't pass the entire data frame to my function in dask - as there is a limitation with its `apply` function. And I tried to use dask apply on my gr1 (group), but since I am setting index in my custom function, dask throws an error saying "Too many indexers".

Here with Dask, this gives me an error - '`Pandas' object has no attribute 'city'`

```
ddf1 = dd.from_pandas(test, 2)
ddf2 = dd.from_pandas(test2, 2)

dgr1 = ddf1.groupby('city')
dgr2 = ddf2.groupby('city')

meta = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Address1', 'score', 'idx','source_index'])
ddf1.map_partitions(custom_func, x.Address1, dgr2.get_group(x.city).Address1,meta=meta).compute()
```

Comment: take a look at `dask` , it is well integrated with pandas.

Comment: Yeah saw that, but dask does not support passing data frame with apply function. Second thing, when I tried to apply dask on group, it fails with "too many indexers" as I am trying to set index inside my custom_func.

Comment: dask apply should work row wise, for column wise use map_partition. may be it is cool you edit your question with what you tried and errors reported.

Comment: Edited as mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: I think your custom_function is creating a writing block in my solution, would be easier if can you give simple example of your custom_func? or explain what you want to do by grouping because i feel there might be better ways of doing it.

Comment: Here my function - https://paste.ofcode.org/NRRTMweDKdmaKRyUPHFkvk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147357/discussion-between-ds-user-and-suvy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I provide an alternative solution to using dask here,

```
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool
test = pd.DataFrame({'Address1':['123 Cheese Way','234 Cookie Place','345 Pizza Drive','456 Pretzel Junction'],'city':['X','U','X','U']}) 
test2 = pd.DataFrame({'Address1':['123 chese wy','234 kookie Pl','345 Pizzza DR','456 Pretzel Junktion'],'city':['X','U','Z','Y'] , 'ID' : ['1','3','4','8']})

test=test.assign(dataset = 'test')
test2=test2.assign(dataset = 'test2')

newdf=pd.concat([test2,test],keys = ['test2','test'])
gpd=newdf.groupby('city')
def my_func(mygrp):
    test_data=mygrp.loc['test']
    test2_data=mygrp.loc['test2']
    #do something specific
    #if needed print something
    return {'Address':test2_data.Address1.values[0],'ID':test2_data.ID.values[0]} #return some other stuff

mypool=Pool(processes=2)
ret_list=mypool.imap(my_func,(group for name, group in gpd))

pd.DataFrame(ret_list)
```

returns something like

```
    ID  address
0   3   234 kookie Pl
1   1   123 chese wy
2   8   456 Pretzel Junktion
3   4   345 Pizzza DR
```

PS: In OP's question two similar datasets are compared in a specialized function, the solution here uses `pandas.concat` . One could also imagine a `pd.merge` depending on the problem.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your help. Keep getting this memory error. :( `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 98, in <module>
    main()
  File "script.py", line 87, in main
    ret_list=mypool.map(my_func,(group for name, group in gpd))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
MemoryError`

Comment: Though I have got 32GB RAM and 256GB disk space. It didn't help much here. I think, pool.map copies the whole data in to every sub process which is leading to memory issue. I don't need any data from parent process apart from what I pass. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Yaa map will make a list of iterator which is intensive, so please use mypool.imap instead.

Comment: Ok let me try that

Comment: Anything to change inside thee function?

Comment: Right now nothing more, just imap instead of map

Comment: Ok, running now, lets see.

Comment: Yeah it was running with out any memory issue. But now this issue. - `ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series`. :(

Comment: This error on this line - `result = pd.concat(ret_list, axis=0)`

Comment: as mentioned in the solution, return a dictionary from your function then your life might be easy creating a  dataframe.

Comment: Sorted it now. Thank you very much. :)